# JavaScript access variables from another function

Tags: javascript

I have the flowing code:

```
 QuestionID = 0;
 var score1 = 0;
 var score2 = 0;

 function clickanswer(answer) { 
    QuestionID++;
    if (QuestionID <= 50) {
        if (QuestionID == 2 || QuestionID == 5) {
            score1 = score1 + answer;}
        if (QuestionID == 4 || QuestionID == 7) {
            score2 = score2 + answer; }
    }
}
function useScores(){
   var data1 = score1;
   var data2 = score2; }
```

The clickanswer(answer) is an onlick event function from a button.
How can I use score1 and score2 variables from clickanswer(answer) function in useScores() function?
Thanks.

Comment: first call click answer(call from useScores() ), then you can use score1 and score2 varibales

Comment: since you defined score1 and score2 on top of both function you can use them in both functions.

Comment: score1 and score2 are global variables, so they can be used in all functions.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to increment `QuestionID` *before* deciding how the scores should compute? Looks buggy to me.

Comment: Pass them as parameters.

Comment: I need the computed values of the variables from clickanswer(answer) function. The clickanswer(answer) is an onlick event function from a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean. But I think it's one of these 2.

1. Just call the `useScores()` function at the bottom of your `clickanswer()` function. As `score1` and `score2` are both global variables, they will both be usable in the function. E.g.

   ```
   function clickanswer(answer) { 
       QuestionID++;
       if (QuestionID <= 50) {
           if (QuestionID == 2 || QuestionID == 5) {
               score1 = score1 + answer;}
           if (QuestionID == 4 || QuestionID == 7) {
               score2 = score2 + answer; }
       }
       useScores();
   }
   ```
2. Or else, you're wanting to pass the variables into the `useScores()` function. In which case, something like this might be what you want.

   ```
   function clickanswer(answer) { 
       QuestionID++;
       if (QuestionID <= 50) {
           if (QuestionID == 2 || QuestionID == 5) {
               score1 = score1 + answer;}
           if (QuestionID == 4 || QuestionID == 7) {
               score2 = score2 + answer; }
       }
       useScores(score1, score2);
   }

   function useScores(score_1, score_2){
       var data1 = score_1;
       var data2 = score_2;
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks Andrew, solution 2 was what I needed, it is simple but now I know how to do it.